# rosserial "ImportError: No module named serial"

Tags: ros, serial, debian, beaglebone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow the rosserial tutorial.  I am running Debian 8.5 on Beaglebone Black.  I installed rosserial from source using the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial.git
cd <ws>
catkin_make
```

This ran fine with no errors, got lots of files and directories with "rosserial" in the name :)

Then I'm ready to test, command (from tutorial) is:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB0
```

result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/debian/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes/serial_node.py", line 39, in <module>
    from rosserial_python import SerialClient, RosSerialServer
  File "/home/debian/ros_catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosserial_python/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    exec(__fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/debian/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 44, in <module>
    from serial import *
ImportError: No module named serial
```

All help will be appreciated.

Bob

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238849/rosserial-%22importerror:-no-module-named-serial%22/) by [bsculley](https://answers.ros.org/users/23933/bsculley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2016-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you don't have the python serial module installed; did you install the dependencies for rosserial when you built it?

You can install all of the dependencies for rosserial with rosdep (this should install python-serial):

```
cd <ws>
rosdep install --from-paths src -i
```

That should install python-serial, and any other dependencies. If it doesn't, you can install the python serial module by hand with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-serial
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bsculley](https://answers.ros.org/users/23933/bsculley/) on 2016-07-06**:
Thanks for your helpful answer.  apt-get install worked for me.  That solved the immediate problem which has now moved on to "ImportError: diagnostic_msgs".  I tried to use the same type of apt-get solution but it didn't work.  Neither could I find good instructions to build it from source.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-06**:
The real answer here was to use rosdep, because it should install all of the dependencies. Did you try it?

**Comment by [bsculley](https://answers.ros.org/users/23933/bsculley/) on 2016-07-07**:
I tried the rosdep install command you cited above, but it failed with:

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rosserial_python: No definition of [diagnostic_msgs] for OS [debian]

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-07**:
That's odd. diagnostic_msgs should be part of a standard ROS install; how did you install ROS?

**Comment by [bsculley](https://answers.ros.org/users/23933/bsculley/) on 2016-07-08**:
from source, using the instructions here:  https://gist.github.com/mhaberler/621bc9df63a8f5800b64